# In WP7 XNA game, how do I create a semi-transparent rectangle on screen as a notification message box?

Tags: xna, message, transparent

Is it possible to create a transparent messagebox (rectangle) that can write multiple-line text on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Andy's solution will suffice, but it might take a few tries until you find the transparency you're after and it also involves creating and loading a new resource in your program. Fortunately you can avoid this and can make the process configurable by generating a single transparent pixel at runtime which will stretch to the bounds of the `Rectangle` argument in the `SpriteBatch.Draw(Texture2D, Rectangle, Nullable<Rectangle>, Color)` call:

```
//You can probably turn this in to a re-useable method
Byte transparency_amount = 100; //0 transparent; 255 opaque
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(Device,1,1,false,SurfaceFormat.Color);
Color[] c = new Color[1];
c[0] = Color.FromNonPreMultiplied(255,255,255,transparency_amount);
texture.SetData<Color>(c);
```

Now use the new `texture` variable in your draw call.

As for multi-line text, there is a `SpriteBatch.DrawString()` overload that accepts a StringBuilder argument. Meaning you can in theory go:

```
//configure
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("First line of text");
sb.AppendLine("Second line of text");

//draw
SpriteBatch.DrawString(font, sb, position, Color.White);
```

I'll give you another hint that will help you determine the size of the drawing rectangle for the texture:

```
//spits out a vector2 *size* of the multiline text
Vector2 measurements = font.MeasureString(sb); //works with StringBuilder
```

You can then create a `Rectangle` from this information, and even give it some padding:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(window_x, window_y, (int)measurements.X, (int)measurements.Y);
rectangle.Inflate(5); //pad by 5 pixels
```

Then put everything in to the draw call, including what color to draw the window

```
SpriteBatch.Draw (texture, rectangle, Color.Black); //draw window first
SpriteBatch.DrawString(font, sb, position, Color.GreenYellow); //draw text second
```

The result is a little nicer looking, more automated, and configurable. You should be able to wrap all this stuff in to a re-usable configurable class for your notification messages.

Note: anything other than drawing code should be in LoadContent() or somewhere else, not the actual game's Draw() call.

Pardon any syntactical errors, I've just wrote it off the top of my head.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a texture in something like Paint.NET(free) that allows you to edit alpha values of colours.

set a small region of the texture to white with an alpha value something like 255,255,255,100 (r,g,b,a), the image below has what you need inside the red square though it doesn't show on white obviously.

[image: White Square]

now with [SpriteBatch.Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx) you can draw your texture on to the screen, it'll come out with the alpha value that you set in the texture.

```
// Texture2D is a reference to the texture from above.
// Rectangle is the screen rectangle you want to draw your grey box at.
// Nullable<Rectangle> is the location of the white data inside the red box.
// Color is the colour that you want your grey box to be (grey?)
SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, Rectangle, Nullable<Rectangle>, Color)
```

Use a SpriteFont over the top of that for the text that you want.

Comment: The reason I suggested using a pre defined region on a texture is that you've probably already got a sprite sheet for your game, even if it's only for the UI you should avoid switching textures as much as possible, place this region in to your UI sprite sheet and there is no reason to switch. 

You can also then swap out the sprite sheet for a new UI 'skin' that even controls things like transparency without code changes.